# Vue js how to import a method (vuex mapGetters method) globally to a project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

When I need **vuex's** **mapGetters** method in a component.

Each and every component I have to import it from vuex like this

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
```

This won't be a good practice.
So I tried in my `main.js`

```
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

Vue.use(mapGetters)
```

But this also doesn't works.

How can I import a method global to my project?

Comment: You could make a plugin that would expose `mapGetters` like how state is, so essentially being used like `this.$mapGetters()`

Comment: What do you mean by plugin?

Comment: Referring to the documentation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html

Comment: Instead of making a plugin, you could simply use this.$store.getters, which is already provided by vuex. However, this imho is too long for template code and not descriptive enough (i.e. no single place to see, which getters are used on this component). So I'm also looking for a simple way to import these helpers from vuex by default. Maybe I'll take the custom plugin route :(.

Comment: did you find solution?